# if selection is changed then hide <h5> that contains specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to hide text if the select option is changed and the text contains 12/31/2017

```js
document.getElementById('search-state').onchange = function() {
jQuery("h5:contains('12/31/2018')").css('display', 'none'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="search-state" name="search-state">
                                <option value="chooseState">Please choose a State</option>
                                <option value="AK">AK - Alaska</option>
                                <option value="AL">AL - Alabama</option>
                                <option value="AR">AR - Arkansas</option>
</select>
<h5>12/31/2017</h5>
<h5>02/02/2018</h5>
```

Comment: Yes, I would like to hide this regardless of what is selected.

Comment: Yes, I am using jquery

Comment: Check my answer. Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("h5").first()` and replace `document.getElementById` with `$`.
Remember that you are using `jQuery`. `$("h5").first()first()` will grab the first element of the tag `h5`. You can also use `$("h5:contains('12/31/2017')")`.

```js
$('#search-state').on("change",function() {
  $( "h5" ).first().css( "display", "none" );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="search-state" name="search-state">
                                <option value="chooseState">Please choose a State</option>
                                <option value="AK">AK - Alaska</option>
                                <option value="AL">AL - Alabama</option>
                                <option value="AR">AR - Arkansas</option>
</select>
<h5>12/31/2017</h5>
<h5>02/02/2018</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that fixes all your typos. You were also looking for content that didn't exist in any of your heading elements (your HTML has `<h5>12/31/2017</h5>` but you were looking for `12/31/2018`).

```js
$('#search-state').change(function() {
  $("h5:contains('12/31/2017')").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="search-state" name="search-state">
                                <option value="chooseState">Please choose a State</option>
                                <option value="AK">AK - Alaska</option>
                                <option value="AL">AL - Alabama</option>
                                <option value="AR">AR - Arkansas</option>
</select>
<h5>12/31/2017</h5>
<h5>02/02/2018</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know jQuery very well. I see you are searching for 12/31/2018 instead of 12/31/2017. This may cause your code to not work.

Here you have a pure javascript solutiuon at least. Sorry, but my jQuery-knowledge is poor.

```
document.getElementById("search-state").onchange = function() {
    var h5Array = document.getElementsByTagName("h5");

    for (var i = 0; i < h5Array.length(); i++) {
        if (h5Array[i].innerHTML == "12/31/2017") {
            h5Array[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: You do not want to use **contains** when you're looking for specific text because it's considered inefficient for exact searches.  Also you didn't indicate what content you want to show or hide.  But **toggle** is a great function for merely controlling the visibility of content on your page.  As you can see below, you can place a condition within your toggle function.

You could try the toggle command in jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#search-state").change(function(){    
       $("#answer").toggle($("h5").text()==="12/31/2017"); 
       // if you're just trying to hide first h5
       // $("h5").first().toggle($(this).text()==="12/31/2017");           
  });

});
</script>
<select id="search-state" name="search-state">
                            <option value="chooseState">Please choose a State</option>
                            <option value="AK">AK - Alaska</option>
                            <option value="AL">AL - Alabama</option>
                            <option value="AR">AR - Arkansas</option>
</select>
<h5>12/31/2017</h5>
<h5>02/02/2018</h5>

<p id="answer">Hide or show this text</p>
```